# SQL presto - cross join unnest with ordinality flattening

Tags: sql, hive, presto

Why is my query not flattening the data as expected?

I am querying a table where columns contain arrays. My goal is to unnest the items in the arrays to find unique items and turn those into rows.

```
SELECT
table1.tag_names,
table1.tag_ids, 
rank_position
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (tag_ids, tag_names)
   WITH ORDINALITY as T (tag_ids, tag_names, rank_position)
ORDER BY tag_ids
```

Results:

| tag_names | tag_ids | rank_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["red", "blue", "green"] | [111, 222, 333] | 1 |
| ["red", "blue", "yellow"] | [111, 222, 444] | 4 |

Desired Results:

| tag_names | tag_ids | rank_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "red" | 111 | 1 |
| "blue" | 222 | 2 |
| "green" | 333 | 3 |
| "yellow" | 444 | 4 |

What am I missing?

Updated to use alias, new results below:

| tag_names | tag_ids | rank_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "red" | 111 | 1 |
| "red" | 111 | 10 |
| "red" | 111 | 3 |
| "red" | 111 | 12 |
| "yellow" | 444 | 4 |

Answer (score 2):

You should use alias introduced for the flattened data in the `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` in the select:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (tag_names, tag_ids) AS (
    VALUES (array['red', 'blue', 'green'], array[111, 222, 444])
) 

-- query
select T.tag_names,
   T.tag_ids, 
   rank_position
from dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (tag_ids, tag_names)
   WITH ORDINALITY as T (tag_ids, tag_names, rank_position)
ORDER BY tag_ids
```

Output:

| tag_names | tag_ids | rank_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 111 | 1 |
| blue | 222 | 2 |
| green | 444 | 3 |

**UPD**

`ORDINALITY` does not work across multiple rows, one way to achieve desired result is to flatten the arrays, then use `group by` and `row_number`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (tag_names, tag_ids) AS (
    VALUES (array['red', 'blue', 'green'], array[111, 222, 333]),
     (array['red', 'blue', 'yellow'], array[111, 222, 444])
) 

-- query
select *, row_number() over (order by tag_ids) rank_position
from (
        select T.tag_names,
            T.tag_ids
        from dataset
            CROSS JOIN UNNEST (tag_ids, tag_names) AS T (tag_ids, tag_names)
            GROUP BY T.tag_names, T.tag_ids
    )
ORDER BY tag_ids
```

Output:

| tag_names | tag_ids | rank_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 111 | 1 |
| blue | 222 | 2 |
| green | 333 | 3 |
| yellow | 444 | 4 |

Comment: A step in the right direction, still not getting the results expected but did flatten each tag. Problem now is that each tag name and id is listed multiple times.  


New Results


|tag_names|tag_ids|rank_position|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| "red"| 111|1|
| "red"| 111|10|
| "red"| 111|3|
| "red"| 111|12|
| "yellow"| 444|4|

Comment: @Sean `ORDINALITY` will not work across the different rows, see the update